# R configure error that C99 double complex is required

Tags: c, r, gcc, c99, configure

I am trying to update R to version 3.5.3 on my Centos 7 server with a GCC compiler of version 8.2.0. But when I tried to configure in the home directory of R-3.5.3, it was stuck with the following error:

```
checking complex.h usability... no
checking complex.h presence... no
checking for complex.h... no
checking whether C99 double complex is supported... no
configure: error: Support for C99 double complex type is required.
```

The version information of my GCC compiler is as follows:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --disable-multilib --disable-libmpx --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)
```

Could anyone help me to get rid of such a problem?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

After I checked [the discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-February/059825.html), I thought the `complex.h` might be included wrongly and then I double checked in the `config.h`. But it turned out to be the included `complex.h` was the new header for gcc 8.2.0 as follows:

```
configure:38022: checking complex.h usability
configure:38022: gcc -c -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/  conftest.c >&5
```

Below them, there was another error which was:

```
/usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/complex.h:29:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried again to configure with options `--includedir` and `CXXFLAGS` but both didn't work.

Comment: Interesting... GCC 8.2.0 surely should support `double complex`. Check the `configure` log for what it did try to do?

Comment: GCC version is not enough; also need to know libc version. See [this related discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-February/059825.html)

Comment: The `configure` log will show not only what it tried to do, but also what error message that elicited.  That may be illuminating.

Comment: I checked the discussion and I found that it might be the header was wrong. But in the config.log, the complex.h was actually the one in the directory "/usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0" and there was another include error "fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory". I tried to configure with options --includedir and CXXFLAGS, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue and fixed it by add `gcc-9.3.0_install/include/c++/9.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/` into include path.

when only `gcc-9.3.0_install/include/c++/9.3.0/` was added into the include path, the <bits/c++config.h> could not be found and lead to this error !

Lidong